# Catching event before chrome window closed, in chrome extensions?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to catch the `beforeRemove` event of Chrome browser window.

I only found [`onRemoved`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows.html#event-onRemoved) event, which is fired after the window is closed.
So the sequence is :

1. Browser Window Closed.
2. Event handler is executed.

But, I want to have the event handler executed **before** the window is closed.

How to do so ?

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){

}
```

Usually, onbeforeunload is used if you need to stop the user from leaving the page (ex. the user is working on some unsaved data, so he/she should save before leaving).

Comment: With your solution I cannot get any information about the closed window :( ... I need some info about the closed window especially when dealing with multiple windows, how to get this ?

Comment: @AshrafBashir what kind of info do you need? Chrome probably won't let you access this kind of info.

Comment: My extension creates a sidebar window beside the focused window. When I close the focused window, I close the sidebar too by catching the onRemove event of the focused window; so the last closed window is the sidebar. The problem is when the user is having this option on settings "Continue where I left off" and if he then clicks Google chrome icon, then Google Chrome will open two sidebars, one which is the actual sidebar and the other is the last closed window (which is the sidebar too!) ...

Comment: ... What i need is to make the focused window the last window to close to avoid this scenario. So that when the user clicks Google Chrome icon again he will see two windows: 1- last focused window and 2- the sidebar.